# WHMCS License Addon not working

Tags: whmcs

I have just authored a WHMCS addon module that works great on my server; however, others that have tried to use it are not having success. There are 2 issues...

1) I use the WHMCS License Addon; however, it does not appear that their remote machines are making a successful connection to my machine to validate the license. I use the WHMCS supplied code to handle the connection and validation. No idea on what else to check... Any ideas?

2) I have a database that my script checks to see if the user has the most current version of the script. Access to the database works great from my local machine and RemoteSQL is enabled with a % wildcard so anyone should be able to connect but yet the remote machines do not seem to be able to connect. Here is my info...

```
$link = mysql_connect('gjinternetsolutions.com', 'gj_Guest', 'Password1');
mysql_select_db("gj_Software", $link);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `VersionCheck` where `Software`='RedemptionFee'";
... additional code to display the results
```

Is anyone able to successfully make a remote connection to the above database?

=========== UPDATE ===========

The second issue above has been resolved. We are still having an issue with the licensing code.... Here is what we have....

```
# Values obtained from our database...
$localkey=$row['LocalKey'];
$licensekey=$vars['License'];

$results = RedemptionFee_check_gj_license($licensekey,$localkey);

function RedemptionFee_check_gj_license($licensekey,$localkey="")
{
    $whmcsurl = "http://gjinternetsolutions.com/home/";
    $licensing_secret_key = "####-VALUE REMOVED FOR THIS POST-####"; # Unique value, should match what is set in the product configuration for MD5 Hash Verification
    $check_token = time().md5(mt_rand(1000000000,9999999999).$licensekey);
    $checkdate = date("Ymd"); # Current date
    $usersip = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] : $_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR'];
    $localkeydays = 1; # How long the local key is valid for in between remote checks
    $allowcheckfaildays = 5; # How many days to allow after local key expiry before blocking access if connection cannot be made
    $localkeyvalid = false;
    if ($localkey) {
        $localkey = str_replace("\n",'',$localkey); # Remove the line breaks
        $localdata = substr($localkey,0,strlen($localkey)-32); # Extract License Data
        $md5hash = substr($localkey,strlen($localkey)-32); # Extract MD5 Hash
        if ($md5hash==md5($localdata.$licensing_secret_key)) {
            $localdata = strrev($localdata); # Reverse the string
                $md5hash = substr($localdata,0,32); # Extract MD5 Hash
            $localdata = substr($localdata,32); # Extract License Data
            $localdata = base64_decode($localdata);
            $localkeyresults = unserialize($localdata);
            $originalcheckdate = $localkeyresults["checkdate"];
            if ($md5hash==md5($originalcheckdate.$licensing_secret_key)) {
                $localexpiry = date("Ymd",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-$localkeydays,date("Y")));
                if ($originalcheckdate>$localexpiry) {
                    $localkeyvalid = true;
                    $results = $localkeyresults;
                    $validdomains = explode(",",$results["validdomain"]);
                    if (!in_array($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $validdomains)) {
                        $localkeyvalid = false;
                        $localkeyresults["status"] = "Invalid";
                        $results = array();
                    }
                    $validips = explode(",",$results["validip"]);
                    if (!in_array($usersip, $validips)) {
                        $localkeyvalid = false;
                        $localkeyresults["status"] = "Invalid";
                        $results = array();
                    }
                    if ($results["validdirectory"]!=dirname(__FILE__)) {
                        $localkeyvalid = false;
                        $localkeyresults["status"] = "Invalid";
                        $results = array();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!$localkeyvalid) {
        $postfields["licensekey"] = $licensekey;
        $postfields["domain"] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $postfields["ip"] = $usersip;
        $postfields["dir"] = dirname(__FILE__);
        if ($check_token) $postfields["check_token"] = $check_token;
        if (function_exists("curl_exec")) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $whmcsurl."modules/servers/licensing/verify.php");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        } else {
            $fp = fsockopen($whmcsurl, 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);
            if ($fp) {
            $querystring = "";
                foreach ($postfields AS $k=>$v) {
                    $querystring .= "$k=".urlencode($v)."&";
                }
                $header="POST ".$whmcsurl."modules/servers/licensing/verify.php HTTP/1.0\r\n";
            $header.="Host: ".$whmcsurl."\r\n";
            $header.="Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
            $header.="Content-length: ".@strlen($querystring)."\r\n";
            $header.="Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
            $header.=$querystring;
            $data="";
            @stream_set_timeout($fp, 20);
            @fputs($fp, $header);
            $status = @socket_get_status($fp);
            while (!@feof($fp)&&$status) {
                $data .= @fgets($fp, 1024);
                $status = @socket_get_status($fp);
            }
            @fclose ($fp);
            }
        }
        if (!$data) {
            $localexpiry = date("Ymd",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-($localkeydays+$allowcheckfaildays),date("Y")));
            if ($originalcheckdate>$localexpiry) {
                $results = $localkeyresults;
            } else {
                $results["status"] = "Invalid";
                $results["description"] = "Remote Check Failed";
                return $results;
            }
        } else {
            preg_match_all('/<(.*?)>([^<]+)<\/\\1>/i', $data, $matches);
            $results = array();
            foreach ($matches[1] AS $k=>$v) {
                $results[$v] = $matches[2][$k];
            }
        }
        if ($results["md5hash"]) {
            if ($results["md5hash"]!=md5($licensing_secret_key.$check_token)) {
                $results["status"] = "Invalid";
                $results["description"] = "MD5 Checksum Verification Failed";
                return $results;
            }
        }
        if ($results["status"]=="Active") {
            $results["checkdate"] = $checkdate;
            $data_encoded = serialize($results);
            $data_encoded = base64_encode($data_encoded);
            $data_encoded = md5($checkdate.$licensing_secret_key).$data_encoded;
            $data_encoded = strrev($data_encoded);
            $data_encoded = $data_encoded.md5($data_encoded.$licensing_secret_key);
            $data_encoded = wordwrap($data_encoded,80,"\n",true);
            $results["localkey"] = $data_encoded;
        }
        $results["remotecheck"] = true;
    }
    unset($postfields,$data,$matches,$whmcsurl,$licensing_secret_key,$checkdate,$usersip,$localkeydays,$allowcheckfaildays,$md5hash);
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can connect using the details above.

Query run:

```
SELECT * FROM `gj_Software`.`VersionCheck` where `Software`='RedemptionFee'
```

Result:

```
# Software, Version, URL
'RedemptionFee', '1.0', 'http://GJinternetSolutions.com/home/upgrade.php?type=package&id=660'
```

Hope this helps.

Ash